# Identify a story in which two kids visit each others' minds while sleeping

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

They're both teenagers or so. He's the prince of an eastern European country, she's middle-American middle class. They were both born with a "disorder" that causes them to occasionally fall asleep for an hour or two at odd times but isn't otherwise harmful. What no one else knows is that when one is asleep, that one's consciousness visits the mind of the other, and thus the two have been growing up together despite having never met. There's a plot (by an uncle, I think) to use the prince's illness to keep him from inheriting the throne, and maybe eventually an assassination attempt. Meanwhile, the royal family is touring the United States, the kids arrange to finally actually meet each other, and stuff gets weird (their consciousnesses start overlapping all the time, even when awake).

I think I read it around 1997-1998, and it felt fairly modern at the time (the language/culture wasn't notably dated). So I expect that it was written in the 90s or maybe 80s.

Comment: I recall a webcomic where kids are aware of each other when they're dreaming. But they're at opposite sides of the world, so the one is always awake when the other is asleep. That's not it, is it?

Comment: Nope, this was before I discovered webcomics. Should've added an approximate year to the question, I'll do that now.

Comment: @MrLister You probably recall [Dreamless](http://dreamless.keenspot.com/), but he's Japanese in that comic, and nothing like a price.

Comment: The dreamsharing and reunion in america remind me of [The Gatekeepers (aka. The Power of Five)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Five) but the times don't match up though. The times match up much better with the Pentagram series, which The Gatekeepers is a reimagination of....

Comment: I'm not aware of this book being part of a series, although I wouldn't necessarily be if it was. It definitely didn't have the occult theme that it sounds like the Horowitz novels do.

Comment: Also, to clarify: they're not dreaming per se, just one body appears asleep while that person's mind is visiting the (fully awake) other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [*Being of Two Minds*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/65101.Being_of_Two_Minds) by Pamela F. Service.

> Connie Hendricks was a typical American teen except for her dizzy spells, when she would pass out. When this happened, she entered the mind and soul of Prince Rudolph, the fourteen-year-old heir apparent of Thulgaria, a small European country. Prince Rudolph had spells too, when he entered Connie's mind and life. Everything was just fine, and their "trick" was their special secret -- until Rudolph was kidnapped while Connie was inside his mind . . .

Comment: You really need to add more details. I've added a Goodreads summary for you. Also, please use your shift key where it applies... capitalization exists for a reason.

Comment: So it is! Thank you! I wonder if it would hold up to an adult re-read ...

Comment: Answer: the story's a little simple but the premise, characters, and writing are still nice. :)