# Young adult novel about a boy and girl who could see through each other's eyes

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

They were born at the same time. One lived in the USA and the other in Germany. Each would have "episodes" where one would pass out and then would see through the awake one's eyes. This is how they grew up, until one day the boy was kidnapped and she had to go save him. He was born into a royal or noble family. The story is then about her trying to save him before it was too late. The world is otherwise normal and there are no other powers or psychic people that are described in the book.

I read it in 1996 in my high school library.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall what the cover looked like?

Comment: I read it in 1996 in my high school library. I don't remember the cover.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify a story in which two kids visit each others' minds while sleeping](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85304/identify-a-story-in-which-two-kids-visit-each-others-minds-while-sleeping)

Comment: @Basya No confirmation from OP yet.

Comment: @Basya - Although this question does sound like it's asking about the same novel, it shouldn't be flagged for closure until the OP confirms that it's the same. In the meantime, why not post an answer here yourself?

Answer (score 15):

[Being of Two Minds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0449704157) by Pamela F. Service (the answer to [this similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85304/identify-a-story-in-which-two-kids-visit-each-others-minds-while-sleeping?rq=1)) sounds like the answer to yours.  An American teenager and a European prince (of an imaginary country, apparently) occasionally have some kind of dizzy spell and then merge with the other.

[Kirkus Reviews](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/pamela-f-service/being-of-two-minds/) describes:

> Connie Hendricks, 14, is an American schoolgirl, while Rudolph, also
> 14, is crown prince of Thulgaria—but their minds are so nearly
> identical that they sometimes merge: Connie (or Rudolph) seems to go
> to sleep while his (or her) mind becomes a guest in the other's, able
> to see and hear everything that goes on. While these periods of sudden
> unconsciousness make their families understandably nervous, and also
> leads to the suspicion that Rudolph is not fit for the monarchy, the
> phenomenon proves valuable when Rudolph is kidnapped by political
> opportunists and when Connie, quickly flying to Thulgaria, is able to
> rescue him.